# React Native: wake a locked phone and play a sound

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, audio, react-native

I am building a **running app** that shows a timer. When the timer reaches 0 seconds a sound is played. I use [React Native Sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) for playback. I use an interval on componentDidMount for counting the seconds:

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.recalcTotalSeconds();

    KeepAwake.activate();

    this._interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.step();
    }, 999);
}
```

It works nicely as long as the phone is unlocked. When the phone is locked the interval is **not fired** and the sound is not played. As a first measure I uploaded a version with [Keep Awake](https://github.com/corbt/react-native-keep-awake) that prevents the screen from locking. I am looking for a battery-friendly solution.

[image: timer screen]

How can I set a timeout to wake the phone up or at least play a sound to alert the user to unlock the phone? How can I play sound in the background when the phone is locked?

Comment: You have to schedule a local notification; you can't rely on your app executing while the phone is locked

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, trying this approach now with https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Answer (score 0):

I have found one workaround for android which allows you to prevent the screen from going to sleep while your app is active. I have used it for audio and it works for me with the help of **react-native-keep-awake** module.

Here's [the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keep-awake/)!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way which allows you to play the track even when screen goes to sleep/locked. I have used **@react-native-community/audio-toolkit** to implement the same.

```
soundOne = new Player('sound_example.mp3', { continuesToPlayInBackground: true });
```

Here's [the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/audio-toolkit)!

Thanks!